# Python ctypes giving segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I was trying to use ctypes for the famous re2 library. But I am getting segmentation fault.

Here's the code

tryone.cpp

```
#include <re2/re2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace re2;

RE2 re("([^ @]+)@([^ @]+)");

std::pair<string, string> match(string rawtext){
    string uname;
    string domain;
    RE2::PartialMatch(rawtext, re, &uname, &domain);
    return std::make_pair(uname, domain);
}

bool isit(string rawtext){
    return RE2::PartialMatch(rawtext, re);
}

extern "C" {
    bool there(string rawtext){ return isit(rawtext); }
}

int  main() {
    if(isit("zbcd@xyz.com")){
    printf("PASS\n");
    }
}
```

Then I compiled with g++

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -c -fPIC -std=c++11 tryone.cpp -lre2 -pthread -o tryone.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmatch.so -L/usr/local/lib -lre2 -o libmatch.so  tryone.o /usr/local/lib/libre2.so.0
```

Here's my python wrapper function

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p, c_bool
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libmatch.so')

lib.there.argtypes = [c_char_p]
lib.there.restype = c_bool

print lib.there("abcd@xyz.com")
```

But when I run the python code its giving me segmentation fault  python wrapper.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, judging from the name and the part you're calling this "re2" library (which is so famous I was unaware of it; while it's in Debian, nothing seems to require it) is a regular expression library. You already have a quite flexible one in Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

Secondly, `ctypes` is the unsafe interface for native libraries; you need to get everything exactly right, which means understanding the underlying type system, including such things as when memory may be allocated or freed and by which routines. Its normal use case is wrapping libraries that have C interfaces without writing any non-Python code. In this case, memory allocation ought to be easy since you're just returning a bool and not keeping the string reference.

But most importantly, C++ [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) simply is not a `char*` as you described it (in fact, C does not have a string data type!). In C++ the type based name mangling used to allow function overloading would have made this evident, since you would not have found a `bool there(char*)` function, but with `extern "C"` you use C's linkage which takes the name exactly; and `ctypes` gets all its type information from your wrapper. You could fix your `there()` wrapper by constructing a string from the char pointer (though you should pass the length also, as Python strings may contain nul), but this exercise seems a roundabout way to make things harder.

Considering your approach requires both a C and a Python wrapper, with no compiler to type check the combination, you might be better served using something like [swig](http://www.swig.org/).